# Lg v35 SLO mo videos playback on PC

Tags: lg, video-recording

So i captured a couple of SLO mo videos with my LG V35 Camera and they play fine on the phone (showing the SLO motion), but when I copied them to my Windows PC and used Adobe Premiere and VLC to play them back they played at reguly speed, how do I see them in SLO motion.
I suspect the 240fps is encoded but how can I just get the SLO mo video without having to re-render it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to export the video. This reddit [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgv20/comments/5ioyrn/how_do_i_export_slow_motion_videos/dba7qol) is for the V20, but should be similar to the V35.

> After shooting the slow mo video, open that video up, hit the edit button(pen) then use the sliders to choose what you want saved in 1/8 or 1/4 or 1/2 or 1x speed then hit save.